# IIS Config HTTP OPTIONS returns 200 but with empty response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET Web API application running on .NET 4.0 with MVC 4.0. This is running on IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition.

When I make a HTTP `GET` request to `myserver/api` I get a response with HTTP status code `200` (or `401` if not logged in) with appropriate content.

But when I make a HTTP `OPTIONS` request to the same url I always get a response with status code `200` and an empty response body (`Content-length = 0`).

Also I get this response when I make a HTTP `OPTIONS` request to a non-existent url (for example, `myserver/api/foo`).

The `OPTIONS` verb is allowed in my `web.config` file.

The problem is present only on one server, others work correctly.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Sounds to me like the web server isn't configured the way you expect. Make sure the IIS configuration on that server matches the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS has a default OPTIONSVerbHandler that might catch the request before MVC does. 
If you remove that handler, your application should handle the request and return the correct response.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
```